# Addition background images instead of replace them

Tags: css

Is there a way to apply multiple background on a same element with multiple rules ?

For exemple, something like that :

```
.a { background-image: url( a.jpg ); }
.b { background-image: url( b.jpg ); }
```

And having two overlapping background on my div :

```
<div class="a b"></div>
```

Or is it required to use an inner element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple background images on a single element:

```
.a { background-image: url(a.png), url(a.png);
     background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-y;
     background-position: 0 0, 0 0; }
```

Then in the `HTML`:

```
<div class="a"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, but is it possible with multiple rules ?

Comment: Note this is a CSS3 only feature.

Comment: @NisonMaël No, the latest style (or definition with highest specificity) will override the other/s.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? You can definitely pull it off even without CSS3, if that doesn't work for you

Comment: If you're interested in which browsers support multiple backgrounds you can see a support chart here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds